# Issue running app (W/art: Failed execv)

Tags: android, xml

When I try to run my app in a phone or an emulator it doesn't launch. There are no messages from the Gradle Build. This is what shows up in the Android Monitor:

```
04-28 20:04:11.651 21225-21225/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-28 20:04:11.818 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:11.889 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:11.955 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.016 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.076 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.134 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.194 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.254 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.315 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.374 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.434 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-28 20:04:12.437 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao-2/lib/arm64
04-28 20:04:12.444 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-28 20:04:12.866 21225-21225/com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21225 SIG: 9
```

Here are my XML files, which I barely touched since most of the coding is in Java.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.funfeast.hollowlightultimaversao">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have no drawables and I didn't touch any other XML outside of these two.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any native code? This looks like a C error

Comment: No. I actually dont think this logcat prints the problem. I'm now creating a new project and copying everything. I'm pretty sure this is some issue with the gradle build or something

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43745313/486312

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the answer.

```
Rect someRect;`
public void someClass () {
     someRect.set(l,t,r,b);
```

In some part of the code I forgot to assign "new Rect" to the Rect variable. Dumb me.

Thanks anyways

Comment: it happens on newly created project (without any code), is it really doesn't happen too you anymroe?